# How to Loop actions between CSV header and Dictionary Keys

Tags: python, pandas, loops, csv, dictionary

I have a dictionary with set of Keys & Values and also have CSV file with columns have the same header name of the dictionary Keys.

i need to apply common function which is if the value of the row of the header that has the name of the key is less than the value defined in the dictionary to write true in a new column in the data set.

the problem is i need to make a loop for all columns to match the header name with the Key name and apply the function according to the value of the key on all column rows.

Below code if i did it with out loop , but if the dictionary increased it will be not efficient way.

Code:

```
dict = {'RRC_SR%' : 99, 'RAB_SR%' : 97, 'UL_UE_Throughput' : 2, 'PS_CDR%' : 0.15, 'DL_UE_Throughput' : 17,
    'INTRA HO SR %' : 99}
kpi = pd.read_csv('KPIs for Triggering.csv')
kpi['RRC_SR Result'] = kpi.loc[:, 'RRC_SR%'].apply(lambda x:x>dict['RRC_SR%'])
kpi['RAB_SR Result'] = kpi.loc[:, 'RAB_SR%'].apply(lambda x:x>dict['RAB_SR%'])
kpi['UL_UE_Throughput Result'] = kpi.loc[:, 'UL_UE_Throughput'].apply(lambda x:x>dict['UL_UE_Throughput'])
kpi['PS_CDR Result'] = kpi.loc[:, 'PS_CDR%'].apply(lambda x:x>dict['PS_CDR%'])
kpi['DL_UE_Throughput Result'] = kpi.loc[:, 'DL_UE_Throughput'].apply(lambda x:x>dict['DL_UE_Throughput'])
kpi['INTRA HO SR Result'] = kpi.loc[:, 'INTRA HO SR %'].apply(lambda x:x>dict['INTRA HO SR %'])


Time    Object  DL_UE_Throughput    UL_UE_Throughput    PS_CDR% RAB_SR% RRC_SR% INTRA HO SR %
0:00    A_1 4.76    1.04    0.17    99.88   99.98   98.22
0:00    B_2 8.1 1.04    0.15    99.92   99.99   97.8
0:00    C_3 5.63    0.72    0.11    99.94   99.98   96.17
0:00    D_4 8.65    1.06    0.25    99.75   99.95   99.51
0:00    E_5 10.21   0.59    0.37    99.67   99.97   99.18
0:00    F_6 7.46    0.34    0.38    99.3    99.95   99.56
0:00    G_7 10.08   2.31    0.6 99.38   99.73   93.63
0:00    H_8 10.29   1.29    0.84    99.5    99.84   99.22
0:00    I_9 10.19   4.76    0.92    99.26   99.75   97.66
0:00    J_10    7.45    8.6 0.85    99.29   99.72   98.55
```

Comment: Could you post a few lines of the CSV so we could experiment? Also, `dict` is a python builtin that your code overwrites, confusing the reader and destroying the ability to build dicts with `dict()`. I strongly suggest calling the dictionary something different.

Comment: @PeterLeimbigler

Object
A_1
B_2
C_3
D_4
E_5
F_6
G_7
H_8
I_9
J_10
DL_UE_Throughput
4.76
8.1
5.63
8.65
10.21
7.46
10.08
10.29
10.19
7.45
UL_UE_Throughput
1.04
1.04
0.72
1.06
0.59
0.34
2.31
1.29
4.76
8.6
PS_CDR%
0.17
0.15
0.11
0.25
0.37
0.38
0.6
0.84
0.92
0.85
RAB_SR%
99.88
99.92
99.94
99.75
99.67
99.3
99.38
99.5
99.26
99.29
RRC_SR%
99.98
99.99
99.98
99.95
99.97
99.95
99.73
99.84
99.75
99.72
INTRA HO SR %
98.22
97.8
96.17
99.51
99.18
99.56
93.63
99.22
97.66
98.55

Comment: Could you please edit this into the original question, formatted as code, so we could copy it and use `pd.read_clipboard`?

Comment: Why do you use apply? You could just apply the comparison to the whole column which is a lot faster: df['res'] = df['A']>d['A'] where df is your dataframe, d is your dictionary, A is your column and res is the resulting column.

Comment: @PeterLeimbigler
Done